# Django Custom Backend : Cannot Login when using custom backend for authentication with email

Tags: django, django-authentication

My primary requirement is to have Email authentication. Though my custom authentication backend seems to work fine, `user.is_anoynymous()` function is still `True` even after succesfully authenticating with my custom backend. When using the default authentication model everything seems fine.

views.py:

```
 from testapp.models import *
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse,Http404,QueryDict
 from django.shortcuts import    render_to_response,  RequestContext         
from django.template import Context
from django.core.paginator import Paginator,QuerySetPaginator
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.contrib.auth   import    logout,authenticate,login
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
from testapp.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import ListView
from testapp.backends import EmailBackend
from testapp.backends import EmailBackend

def main_page(request):
    return render_to_response('main_page.html',{
        'user':request.user
    })

def loggedout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def custom_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = request.POST['email']
        password =  request.POST['password1']

        cb = EmailBackend()
        user = cb.authenticate(email,password)
        # return HttpResponse(user.username)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('USer is not Active')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('USer Not found')
else:
    form = LoginForm()
    page_var = RequestContext(request, {
        'form':form, 
    })
    return render_to_response('customlogin.html',page_var)`
```

backends.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self,email= None,password= None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)

            if user is not None:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
                else :
                    return None
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self,user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None`
```

settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('testapp.backends.EmailBackend','django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

main_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Welcome to Django Bookmarks{% endblock %}
{% block head %}Welcome to Django Bookmarks{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% block customadd %}
    kskdsdsdl;sd
    {% endblock %}
{% if user.username %}
<p>Welcome {{ user.username }}!
Here you can store and share bookmarks!</p>
{% else %}
<p>Welcome anonymous user!
You need to <a href="/login/">login</a>.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now although the main_page.html is called after successfully authentication, In main page `{{user.username}}` is always `None` and hence main_page.html opens as anonymous user.

`user.is_anonymous()` in main_page function in view.py returns `True`. What mistake am I making? After redirect to main_page.html I should see the user as logged in.

**Edit 1:** Last time I purposefully didn't put all the packages I included in views.py so I updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

Django provides a [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). I recommend that you use this rather than writing your own.

If you use the Django login view, Django will use your authentication backend, because you have added it to the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

You would need to make a small change to the backend - change the field name from `email` to `username` so that it matches the login form. You would still filter the user based on their email.

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password= None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
```

If you continue to use your own login view, I can see a couple of possible issues. Firstly, you should import the [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) method, and call that instead of instantiating your login backend.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def custom_login(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    ...
```

Secondly, when you call `login(request, user)`, make sure you have imported the correct `login` method, and not the `login` view I mentioned above.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alasdair. I purposefully didn't put all the packages I included in views.py ,Now I updated it .So I dont think there is an Import error.

Comment: Moreover cb.authenticate(email=email,password=password) works fine as I get the correct username if I return a HttpResponse(user.username) which I have hashed here. I think the issue is with the login(request,user) function and something to do with sessions not getting stored.

Comment: You have `from django.contrib.auth.views import *`, which is replacing the login method `login` with the login view `login`.

Comment: Even if calling `cb.authenticate` works, I recommend that you call `authenticate`. If you do things differently than recommended, then you're more likely to hit weird bugs that can be hard to fix.

Comment: Thanks mate that was the problem. login function was getting overwritten by login view.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. I'd recommend using [Python's logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to aid in troubleshooting this.

Based on my own painful experience using email for authentication, you'll want to match case-insensitively because a *lot* of people will enter TheirEmail@likeThis.com.  :)

```
user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
```

...or *only* store lowercase email addresses.  One project I worked on ended up with duplicate entries due to this.

Also, if that query succeeds, user will never be `None`, so you can skip that test and simplify your try-except block:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
    if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    else:
        logger.debug('password check failed')

except User.DoesNotExist:
    logger.debug('user does not exist')

return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Thomas. If you look at my views.py , after the line:-     cb=authenticate(email=email,password=password) , i have a hashed an HtppResponse with  username. when i uncomment that , I can see the correct user name returned as the response. So I don't think lowercase is the issue. The problem is, I am authenticated in the login function but that does not hold while I am redirecting to a new page. Do you think I have to write a custom login(request) function too? I am suspecting it has someting to do with my session not holding on?